# Laravel return error messages from custom validation

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find any solution on how to display error messages from custom validation. I can not find it even on StackOverflow.
My problem is that I have my controller and I need to validate some stuff in my custom class.

Controller:

```php
public function store()
{
    $customStuff = new MyTestClass();

    $variable =  $customStuff->myCustomValidation(5 );
    
    return view('test.index', compact('variable'));
}
```

And custom class:

```php
namespace App\Classes;

class MyTestClass
{
    public function myCustomValidation($a = null, $b = null)
    {
        if (empty($a))
        {
            dd('error 1'); // how to throw message here
        }
        elseif (empty($b))
        {
            dd('error 2');  // how to throw message here
        }
        else
        {
            return ($a + $b);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a sample code. I know how to use `Validator` inside `Controller` but is it possible to return an error back to the user if something is wrong in the custom `class`? Instead of `dd()`, it has to be an error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return that the validation failed to your view then do

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Message here!']);
```

And if you return as a API response then do

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'Message here!'], 404); // Or any other status code
```

Comment: I have this in my blade after your suggestion:    HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 10:30:51 GMT Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/test'" /> <title>Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/test</title> </head> <body> Redirecting to <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test">http://127.0.0.1:8000/test</a>. </body> </html>

Comment: Okay, then try return redirect()->route('test')->with('error', 'Message here!'); But change the route to the route you want to redirect to after validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

class MyTestClass
{
    public function myCustomValidation($a = null, $b = null)
    {
        abort_if(empty($a), 403, 'error 1');
        abort_if(empty($b), 403, 'error 2');

        return ($a + $b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you created a plain Class for validation?

You can use [laravel rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) if you are trying to create a custom validator

If you don't want to use a validator you can set a [flash message](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#flash-data)

Comment: Yes I have a custom plain class for validation and I will store all my generic validations inside this class